# Pygame Timer Error (numbers print on top of eachother)

Tags: python, pygame

I am making an rpg and one of the elements of the game is hunger. Hunger increases by 1 every minute and if you get to 10 you "die" (pygame crashes). You can also buy food items to make your hunger go down, however I haven't added that in yet. Currently, the timer works to increase hunger level by 1 each minute but the minute values (1,2,3,4,5 etc) print on top of eachother on the screen.
(Also, please ignore the odd food items in the store haha)

Can someone please help me fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys 

mainClock=pygame.time.Clock()
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()

def draw_text(text, font, color, surface, x, y):
    textobj=font.render(text, 1, color)
    textrect=textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft=(x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

#Defining the store building on the map
 def store():
    global click

    font=pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 50,)
    colorC = (238,59,59)
    (widthC, heightC) = (1000, 800)
    screenC = pygame.display.set_mode((widthC, heightC))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Store')
    screenC.fill(colorC)
    draw_text('Inside The Store:', font, (0,0,0), screenC, 20,        20)

    mx, my=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    cheetos_button=pygame.Rect(20, 325, 475, 50)
    mx, my=pygame.mouse.get_pos()                
    buttonC_color=(156,102,31)
    pygame.draw.rect(screenC, (buttonC_color), cheetos_button)
    text=font.render("Hot Cheetos: $5, -1 Hunger", True,(0,0,0))
    screenC.blit(text, (20,325))
    cheetoImg=pygame.image.load("hotcheetos.png")
    x=20
    y=50
    screenC.blit(cheetoImg, (x, y))

    mx, my=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    icedtea_button=pygame.Rect(20, 585, 475, 50)
    mx, my=pygame.mouse.get_pos()                
    buttonC_color=(156,102,31)
    pygame.draw.rect(screenC, (buttonC_color), icedtea_button)
    text=font.render("Iced Tea: $5, -2 Hunger", True,(0,0,0))
    screenC.blit(text, (20,585))
    icedteaImg=pygame.image.load("icedtea.png")
    x=15
    y=380
    screenC.blit(icedteaImg, (x, y))

    mx, my=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    pizza_button=pygame.Rect(525, 585, 475, 50)
    mx, my=pygame.mouse.get_pos()                
    buttonC_color=(156,102,31)
    pygame.draw.rect(screenC, (buttonC_color), pizza_button)
    text=font.render("Pizza Slice: $20, -5 Hunger", True,  (0,0,0))
    screenC.blit(text, (525,585))
    cheetoImg=pygame.image.load("pizza.png")
    x=450
    y=75
    screenC.blit(cheetoImg, (x, y))

    font=pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 25,)
    text=font.render("Your Money:", True,(0,0,0))
    screenC.blit(text, (400,20))
    currentM=0
    font=pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 25,)
    text=font.render(str(currentM), True,(0,0,0))
    screenC.blit(text, (510,20))

    #Hunger Timer
    pygame.init()

    done = False

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    font2 = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)

    frame_count = 0
    frame_rate = 60
    start_time = 90

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
                done = True  

        total_seconds = frame_count // frame_rate

        minutes = total_seconds // 60

        hunger_lvl = frame_count // frame_rate

        minutes = total_seconds // 60

        hunger_lvl = "Hunger Level: {0}".format(minutes)

        text2 = font2.render(hunger_lvl, True, (0,0,0))
        screenC.blit(text2, [700, 20])

        frame_count += 1

        clock.tick(frame_rate)

        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

store()
```

Thank you to anyone who can help me out:)

Comment: Try filling the screen before drawing to it?

Comment: I can't fill it with a blank color though because I need the shop items visible.

Comment: You can use the update function rather than flip and specify a surface. So you only draw the Store once, but you draw the gui each frame for example

Comment: So what would the code look like for that? Sorry, I am very new to coding, I started a couple months ago and this is my first major project.

Comment: You would need to create a Surface to draw the gui into. And Blit the gui Surface to the background. Then you would call Update on the gui Surface. On the other hand you could just redraw everything including the shop each frame.

Comment: Would it work to copy and paste all the code drawing store under the line "for event in pygame.event.get():"?

Comment: normally in `while not done:` you should clear/fill `screenC` and draw all element again. You can also clear/fill only region in which you display time before you draw new value.

Comment: BTW: you should import all modules at start, next do `pygame.init()` (even without `pygame.display.init()`) and later create `Clock()`. And you shouldn't use again `pygame.init()` later. BTW: some function may have to be used after `set_mode()` when `PyGame` know size of window and color depth (ie. 32bit colors)

Comment: Ill try clearing screenC in the while not done and then draw everything again. Edit: how do you clear? Do you have to import something?

Answer (score 1):

Since your "hunger level" is always increasing, using a PyGame timer event seems like a good solution.

It's fairly simple, define your own event based on `pygame.USEREVENT`, and ask `pygame.timer.set_timer()` to start sending you periodic events.

```
# Create an event to generate hunger
hunger_lvl   = 0  # not hungry
HUNGER_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
STARVING     = 10
pygame.time.set_timer( HUNGER_EVENT, 60000 )   # Get a hunger event every 60000ms (1 minute)
```

Then it's just a matter of receiving the event in your main event loop:

```
# handle Event
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True
    elif event.type == HUNGER_EVENT:
        hunger_lvl += 1
        if hunger_lvl >= STARVING:
            print( "player starving in an age of abundance; why..." )
```

That's it.

Comment: So I got the timer working (well for some reason now which I don't know why, the hunger lvl increases every 2 minutes - so now hunger lvl 5 can be considered "starving to death"). Anyways how can I get make it so when the buttons are click (food items purchased) the hunger lvl decreases. I've tried a few things but none seem to work. Do you think you could help me Kingsley? I can post the updated code.

Comment: @dremmy10 - When you draw the icons for the food item, create a PyGame Rect that is the size and position of the image.  E.g.: `pizza_img=pygame.image.load("pizza.png")`, `pizza_rect=pizza_img.get_rect()`, `pizza_rect.topleft = (x,y)`.  Then use `pizza_rect.collidepoint( mouse_click_pos )` to see if the user clicked inside the icon.